# capture "back button" Keypress in android with jquery

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

it is possible to capture the "back button" Keypress in Android  with jquery?.
I ve got a Close Button and I want to use the back button from my Android to close the modal window.

Can this be done without Java, only with JS or jQuery?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can detect it using the keycode

```
$(document).on('keydown', function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == 27) {
      // Prevent default (disable the back button behavior)
      event.preventDefault();

      // Your code
    }
});
```

Comment: It's not recognizing hard-back button keydown event on android devices.

Comment: I tried this solution on Android phones with both hardware and software back button, none did work.